# windows server 2012 r2 not able to connect network after change ip

Tags: windows

I am wondering what is wrong with my windows server 2012 r2 standard, use this server to serve as file server only to replace my current windows server 2003 standard edition.

During installation, setup with ip address `192.168.103.200` and everything ok, after some adjustment and configuration, we decide to take the server to production and change the ip address to the old ip address and power off the old server, which the ip address is `192.168.2.2`, but after change the ip address, the server is not able to connect to other computers and vice versa. Try to change the ip address to `192.168.2.3` and everything is working.

Anyone know what could the cause for this issue?

Comment: You should state or tell us if when you put the new server into production you also changed its name to match the "old" server name or if you gave it a new name.  (And if you turned off the old server).  Also tell us if you are using Active Directory AD - Domain security or if you are in work group mode.  (also tell us if this is the first 2012 r2 server in your production network that is 2012 r2 or higher in version)

Comment: sorry, the change to same as old server as well as the ip address, work in a group mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the source this problem there is network level. Try to ping itself. Make on server ping to 192.168.2.2. If no then this is problem with driver's NIC. But if yes... Then check your network switch or router. There are maybe any settings for MAC address and this IP address(any filter rules your firewall). I'm almost sure this problem is in port access settings in your network equipment.

Comment: at first i thought it was the firewall which block the connection, however the old server which has the same setting has no problem at all. pinging to the server from itself does a reply. however found out that the new server with ip `192.168.2.2` can ping to same network `192.168.2.~`, but it cannot ping to other network in that case is `192.168.103.~` but it i change the new server ip to `192.168.2.3` it can ping both network without any problem, and we are able to connect to it as well.

Comment: check the default gateway setting in new server.

Comment: the default gateway is `192.168.2.1` which is same to the old server. As i mentioned earlier, if change the ip to `192.168.2.3` everything back to normal.

Comment: so if you can: 
1. have access to local network
2. have access to router (do you can ping router?)
3. do non have access to another networks

so, you have bottleneck in your router, don't you?

Comment: i am not sure what u mean `bottleneck in router` everything is okay with old server which is windows 2003. but a new server with windows 2012 R2 with same ip and gateway and has the problem as mentioned earlier.

Comment: I mean you have to check your router. Network communication there are two root address for success communication like MAC address (hardware address) and IP address (network host address). And if you change host you change MAC address. And if you set same IP to another host it doesn't mean that you are having all same. You have another MAC address and it maybe source your problem.

Comment: thank you for your magic word `mac address`, found out that the ip address is bind to the old server mac address in mikrotik hence when we take the new server to production, mikrotik still recognise the old mac address.